# EPiServer 7: Site crashed unless I'm logged in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, episerver, episerver-7

When I enter my webpage I get this in my console:

[image]

If I log in to EPiServer, I do not get the errors, and it seems fixed for a little while, I can even log out and it works for a couple of hours.

Anyone knows what this is?

Comment: Sounds like the `Anonymous` user doesn't have read access to all content like .js and images.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Could you expand a little bit? Is it the user set in the application pool that doesn't have read access? Because that would be wired, since it works when I'm logged in. Is it any anonymous user in EPiServer 7?

Comment: To me it seems that an anonymous user is trying to access resources on the server but is being redirected to the login page for said resources. That suggests that the `Everyone` group cannot access the resources. You need to grant the `Everyone` group read access to the resources. All problematic resources seems to be in the `/Scripts` folder so make sure `Everyone` has read access to it.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. If you want an accepted answer, please make a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems that an anonymous user is trying to access resources on the server but is being redirected to the login page for said resources. That suggests that the `Everyone` group cannot access the resources. You need to grant the `Everyone` group read access to the resources. All problematic resources seems to be in the `/Scripts` folder so make sure `Everyone` has read access to it.